# Will U.S. 3DS work with games from Mexico?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds

I'm living in Mexico. I went to the U.S. and bought a Nintendo 3DS. Will the 3DS read the game if I buy the game in Mexico?

Comment: Do any of your friends have a 3ds? Try their games to see if they run :)

Comment: Nope dont have any that have 3ds

Answer (score 8):

Mexico games share the same region code as the U.S. (NTSC-U) and therefore do function properly in devices from the U.S.

[There's a region list here with explanations.](http://nintendo.wikia.com/wiki/Regions)

> Note that these countries sometimes have games made exclusively for
>   them, usually in French (NTSC-C) and Spanish (NTSC-M) respectively,
>   these games however will still work in the other countries of this
>   region without any modifications or lockout disabling devices.

Comment: @Niñolocz If that answers your question you should consider marking it as the solution. Having said that, make sure the Mexican games don't have the same affect on your 3DS that the water has on American gastrointestinal systems.